# Как расположить элемент с помощью стилей не изменяя html структуры?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

Всем привет. Есть карточка товара с названием, описанием, картинкой и ценой. Нужно зафиксировать цену в определенном положении сразу после заголовка слева не меняя при этом структуры html. Если картинка стандартного размера (325*325) и `Название продукта...` в одну строчку, то все хорошо. Проблема возникает когда картинка может быть любого размера и название тоже на 2ух и более строчек. Как обойти этот момент и желательно с помощью стилей?

```css
.thumbnail-container img {
  display: block;
}
.product-frame {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.product-frame .price {
  position: absolute;
  top: 375px;
  left: 10px;
}
.amount {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-frame ">
  <div class="thumbnail-container">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="front">
        <img src="#" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!--/ .thumbnail-container-->
  <div class="content-description">
    <div class="product-section">
      <h3><a href="#">Название продукта...</a></h3>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <p>Состав...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form class="variations_form cart" method="post">
    <div class="single_variation_wrap">
      <div class="single_variation">
        <span class="price"><span class="amount">260.000&nbsp;руб.</span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="variations_button">
        <button type="submit" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">Купить</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я вас правильно понял то абсолютное позиционирование должно решать вашу проблему.

Я бы убрал его у класса цены css:

```
.price {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
variations_button {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

, а Jquery задавал бы его при необходимости:

```
if ($('.wp-post-image').width() + $('.content-description').width() > 600px){
    $('.price').css("position","absolute");
    $('.price').css("top",($('.wp-post-image').height()/2)+"px");
    $('.price').css("left",($('.wp-post-image').width()/2)+"px");
}
```

Скрипт вам прийдется самому переписать, в зависимости как вы хотите чего отображать...

Comment: спасибо, но если все-таки скриптом обходить это, то как минимум нужно не на `width`, а на `height` ориентироваться. и боюсь, что таким способом тяжело подобрать высоту - будет криво смотреться при разной высоте названия. Если бы как-то можно было привязать цену под заголовок - было бы круто!

Comment: Честно говоря, я до конца не понял что вы хотите получить.
Мне кажется если вы просто откажитесь от абсолютного позиционирования, то всегда цена будет перед кнопкой submit.

Если хотите привязать "цену под заголовок" - зделайте костыль, вырежте из страницы цену и всавте в конец дива с заголовком. Но я бы так не делал а переверстал страницу.
Все также читайте Jquery innerHtml.

Comment: да, все правильно - место расположения должно быть сразу под заголовком, а перед `submit` она полюбому находится.
Не все так просто, я не могу ее просто вырезать и вставить в конец дива - цена находится в `form` (которая передает на сервер данные), если вы это заметили

Comment: и еще - прочитайте, пожалуйста, внимательно вопрос (от этого многое зависит) - в самом названии уже написано, что нужно расположить цену не изменяя структуры html

Comment: Лучше поменять таки темплейт на котором в форме оставить <input type='hidden' ...>, а цену рисовать там где вам нужно.